# Using Google Calendar API's ListRequest to search for events with hyphens

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

If you have a Google Calendar event with a subject like `Hyphens - Are used----as NOT opera-tors-in Google -searches by- the - looks of it -`.

If you use the [ListRequest](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) option in .NET  and set the "Q" property to the same subject of that event it will not find it. You have to replace the hyphen with a space or remove it in order to bring back a match.

Anyone know if can you get around this when using the API? or even if there is documentation around what query parameters we would need to account for when subjects of events have these types of characters in them.

Comment: When using the query parameter on the Try this section of the [api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) it gets the event with no issue. Could it be a .net issue? Can you share the code you are using and how it is returned?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.   I agree check it with the try me if you get the same results i would bug report it [issueForum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B)  If not i would report it to the .net client library [issue forum.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues)

Comment: Sorry, my subject example was a bad one. Try `Hyphens - Are used----as NOT opera-tors-in Google -searches by- the - looks of it -` as the subject. Unusual I know but that should replicate it.

Comment: Have you managed to do it? Could you share the code in order to try it?

Comment: No, nothing yet @Kessy Asked the same question here with some response - https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/88886385?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar issue on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176481046)

You can go there and star it so you get notified when there are updates on it.